# Parsing csv file in c into columns

Tags: c, csv, parsing

I have a project to create a program in C that can read any CSV file given to apply some statistical calculations such as(sum, average, ...etc).

and I am stuck since 1 week to try to parse the csv into 2d array and access the columns to do the sum i.e.

this is what I've done till now :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "functions.h"

int mat[100][100], i = 0, j = 0;

void ReadTab(char FileName[], int input, int NumLine)
{
    char* tokenPointer = NULL;
    char* next_tokenPointer = NULL;
    char separator[] = ";";

    FILE* IN;

    fopen_s(&IN, "DATA.csv", "r");
    if (IN == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to open the file.");
        return 1;
    }

    char line[200];
    int LineCount = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), IN) != NULL)
    {
        tokenPointer = strtok_s(line, separator, &next_tokenPointer);
        LineCount++;

        if (input == 1)
        {
            PrintTab(tokenPointer, separator, next_tokenPointer);
        }
    
        if (LineCount == NumLine)
        {
            break;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(IN);
}

void PrintTab(char* tp, char sep[], char* ntp)
{
    while (tp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %-12s\t", tp);
        mat[1][j++] = atoi(tp);
        tp = strtok_s(NULL, sep, &ntp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like telling us the problem you have with the [mre] you show, how it actually behaves, how it should behave, inputs, outputs (actual and expected), what efforts at debugging you have made, and of course contain an actual question.

Comment: What is the specific question? You probably should not use `strtok` here because it cannot deal with empty columns.

Comment: Also, generic CSV files are *deceptively* easy to parse, but in reality could have lots of corner cases that will make it anything but trivial. Unless the CSV file is guaranteed to be good, never have any errors, and never use any of the non-trivial special cases, I recommend that you find a library which handle them for you.

Comment: do you have a specific format for the input CSV files? Are there line breaks or carriage returns which signify rows?  I would try to break this problem down into steps. Don't go for the matrix right away. First, create an array of strings which represent each line in the input file. Use this step to get rid of any unneeded whitespace. Once you solve that, create a function that takes just a single NULL terminated string and returns a vector of values.

Comment: ok so basically the question is this :

Comment: Calculate summary and order statistics for a given column i.e.
a. sum
b. average, standard deviation
c. Minimum and maximum value
d. Median, first and third quartile

Comment: the csv format is a ";" separator

Comment: here is the csv file 'code'

Comment: Age;GA (CTG);GA (b);Sex;B weight (g);A1- min;A 5-min
33;37;39,3;M;3655;9;10
37;31;39,1;F;2875;9;10
38;36;38,1;M;2870;9;10
26;28;40,5;F;3180;9;10
29;38;41,1;F;2950;9;10
40;39;39,4;M;3930;9;10
30;37;39,6;M;3510;9;10
31;35;39,6;F;3550;9;10
28;28;39,2;F;3035;9;10
31;27;37;F;3330;9;10
30;37;38,3;M;3110;9;10
34;38;39,2;F;3090;9;10
39;39;41,1;F;2840;9;10
39;30;40,4;M;3990;9;10
30;29;40;M;3220;8;10
28;33;40,4;F;3470;9;10
31;28;36,6;F;2970;9;10
32;39;41,2;M;3925;9;10
31;37;39,5;M;2990;8;10